# optionally use table prefix in codeigniter using active records

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, prefix

I want to produce sql like:

```
select id, "file_name.png" from prefix_table;
```

In CI, by using active records, I code that with:

```
$this->db->select('id, "file_name.png"', FALSE)->from('prefix_table');
```

but what I got is:

```
select id, prefix_"file_name.png" from prefix_table;
```

Is there any way to use the table prefix optional? Or may be, how do I do not use the prefix when selecting using active records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a limitation/bug in CodeIgniter right now -- you won't be able to use a string like that without the prefix butting in. I'd suggest writing the query manually. I've opened an [issue on Github](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/2353) for it.

Also, you should use an `AS column` definition when selecting a string like that, otherwise the string name will also be the column name, and you'll end up with something like:

```
array(
    'id' => 2,
    'file_name.png' => 'file_name.png'
)
```

Comment: thank you for putting it as a bug in CI (i thought that i'm the one that just got wrong). yes, actually i use the `AS column`; but still no luck. seems that i have no other choice (with active records) but waiting until the bug fixed, right?

Comment: You could use `CONCAT()` to "trick" it into not prefixing the name, but that'll slow down your query and is unnecessary to add the same item to every result. You should just run the active record query without it, and add the item to each result row manually.